# Angular7 Runtime compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to compile a HTML string into Angular component.

I have a HTML string something like this:

```html
<test-card></test-card>
<test-card></test-card>
<test-card></test-card>
....
```

There's already `test-card` component in my Angular project.

So what I need is injecting an external Angular template string to my Angular view.

Here's expected result.

```html
<div class="card"> ... </div>
<div class="card"> ... </div>
<div class="card"> ... </div>
```

- I know this is not a good option and another way to accomplish it. But basecode is not mine and I don't have enough time to change entire codes.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 7 doesn't provide runtime compilation of templates like angularJS.

Maybe dynamic components could solve your issue :

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader